# AWS Cognito User Pool force logout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a user pool in AWS, and I am using AWS cognito for authentication to access AWS resources. From my client side application (reactjs), the users can log in, log out, and will be logged out when the browser detects inactivity.

I would like to know if it is possible to configure in AWS the expiration of the user token to "log out" users after a certain number of hours of last requesting an AWS resource (API Gateway) to force them to re-authenticate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `STS` token issued by `AWS Cognito` expires in 1 hour.

Comment: During testing in my app (reactjs).. the user still remains logged in after several hours, including closing and reopening browser. Is that a fault of the app? should I force log out with aws-amplify when browser is closed

Comment: are you authenticating with `Facebook`?

Comment: Cognito, but yes you are correct.. I found your answer in the documentation. I think I may have been mistaken in my testing.. Does amazon allow you to change this value?

Comment: I don't think you can change that.